# Discrepancy between JProfiler and local logging

Tags: java, jprofiler

I am trying to figure out if this value is being cached and I'm not understanding it. We're calling the same method twice and I'm curious how much benefit there is to removing that, so I profiled it. This is what Jprofiler says

```
mainMethod() {
  methodCalledTwice() -> 151ms
  method1()
    methodCalledTwice() -> 9ms
}
```

But when I tried logging it by adding `Duration.between(start, finish)` where start and finish are `Instant.now()` I get 163ms and 151ms

Curious what's creating this discrepancy.

Comment: How is the thread status selector set in the CPU views? By default it is set to "Runnable" which is not comparable to a wall clock time measurement. You would have to switch the thread status selector to "All thread states" for that purpose.

Comment: You should avoid introducing additional overhead when measuring elapsed time. With `Instant.now()` and `Duration.between(…)` you are creating new objects but in the worst case, the classes `Instant` and `Duration` were not used before and you’re measuring the time to load them. Use `long start = System.nanoTime(); /* perform the actual action */ long end = System.nanoTime(); long durationInMillis = (end - start) /1_000_000;`

Comment: Oh this is awesome feedback, let me try updating it. Btw I found the "all thread states" view to be confusing and hard to find where my calls are being made, because of the complexities with spring boot. Is there a way to filter it? Or make it more readable?

Comment: @IngoKegel can you help me understand how all states work? Because it's saying API takes 110s, when the actual API call is about 10s

Comment: `Because it's saying API takes 110s, when the actual API call is about 10s` -> Then you have multiple threads and the times are summed. Select a single thread instead. For more information on thread states, see https://www.ej-technologies.com/resources/jprofiler/help/doc/main/cpu.html

Comment: @IngoKegel perfect thanks, let me read that!